# Using native functions to return views in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

We are considering creating an interface between the database (Postgres) and the JPA (Hibernate/JBoss 7.1.1).

We will define database functions to call and views to return which determine the interface to the database. Basically the JPA code will call stored PostgreSQL functions and it returns views which are mapped to entities.

This interface allows clean modulisation between database and JPA code. However it seems to lose the benefits of JPA (example we must define native queries so Hibernate caching cannot be used).

Does anyone have any advice whether this is a good way to go, or experience with such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use cases you have and the fact if you have to use existing database code.

If you have a chance to choose, then never mix business logic if not necessary - so my advice would be to use JPA entities and queries wherever possible and have all the logic in your java application and use plain SQL or PL/pgSQL only where you need it or benefit from it, e.g. for mass data in reporting or when you need database specific functions.